# Boost_1_72_0 error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

Tags: c++, boost

gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
Boost: 1.72.0

I get the following error while compiling my c++ code:

```
In file included from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:23:0,
                 from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/mpl/apply.hpp:23,
                 from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:36,
                 from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp:27,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:16,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp:11,
from /home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/date_time.hpp:15,
from /home/hadoop/work/db/connection.cpp:6:
/home/hadoop/work/external-lib/boost_1_72_0/boost/mpl/aux_/has_apply.hpp:22:58: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_NAMED_DEF(has_apply, apply, false)
```

The db/connection.cpp file is:

```
#include "connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp> // Error at this line

db::Connection::Connection() {
        m_driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
        m_driver->threadInit();
        m_con = m_driver->connect("tcp://<host>:<port>", "<user>", "<pwd>");
        m_con->setSchema("test");
        m_stmt = m_con->createStatement();
}
```

I don't make any boost::date_time call. Just included the header file (for the time being).

It's worth mentioning that the MySQL code also accesses the boost library (internally), and I don't get any error when I comment out the boost/date_time header file.

Comment: test has been defined to be something else in one of the other header files .  Try including date_time.hpp first.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks a lot. I moved the date_time header to line # 1 and it worked. Is it a bug in Boost?

Comment: You could make a bug with Boost and they might be able to do something.  But I think it is just how each library does things different.  Boost doesn't want to overwrite a macro created by someone else so they check to see if one exists before they define theirs - and since it already existed they didn't overwrite it.  But since if works when Boost is first that means MySQL is overwriting the Boost macro with their own.  If it was a macro you needed to call in main() how would you know which one you were calling since you don't know if one header overwrote the other one's macro or not?